# Mapping Visualisation with GeoIP in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, geoip

I have a pipeline that used geoip

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_ingest/pipeline/geoip?pretty" -d'
     {
  "description" : "Add geoip info",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "geoip" : {
        "field" : "ip", 
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

I pass the data by bulk API in to ELK stack. When trying to visulise the data i have no geo point set. Elastic search has automapped this information as number in two fields.

```
client_geoip.location.lat       59.894
client_geoip.location.lon       30.264
```

I tried creating the two fields as a geo point but when importing due to client_geoip.location.lat amd client_geoip.location.lon not being there it failed.

How do i get geoip to create a geo_point that I can use for mapping visualisation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have just one field of type geo_point, it includes both lat and long.so your client_geoip.location should be of type geo_point

You can configure the target key name for this pipeline if you want 
configure your geoip like-

```
"processors" : [
  {
  "geoip" : {
    "field" : "ip",
    "target_field" : "your_field",
    "database_file" : "GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.gz"
   }
 }
]
```

You can have some mapping  like

```
        "location_field" : {
          "path_match" : "your_field.location",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
          }
        }
```

It should work